# Rails + Rspec: How to test for environment specific actions? e.g. "... unless Rails.env.production?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a wrapper for a payment processor:

```
class PaySimpleWrapper 
  attr_reader :transaction

  def initialize(args={})
    @transaction.usesandbox = true unless Rails.env.production?
  ....
```

How would I test that the usessandbox attribute gets set only in non-production environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  describe PaySimpleWrapper do
    let(:wrapper) { PaySimpleWrapper.new }

    describe "when in production" do
      before { Rails.stub_chain(:env, :production?) { true } }
      it "uses the live system" do
        expect(wrapper.transaction.usesandbox).to be_false
      end
    end

    describe "when not in production" do
      before { Rails.stub_chain(:env, :production?) { false } }
      it "uses the sandbox" do
        expect(wrapper.transaction.usesandbox).to be_true
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: nice one I should've thought of that

Comment: `Rails.env.stub(:production?) { whatever }` is a bit easier.